# Match ID of clicked element to key in json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, svg

I am working on a proof of concept for an interactive USA map. When user clicks on the state shape, text information about that particular state should appear in the div below the map. I have an html file containing two SVG shapes, a JS file, and a JSON file currently containing an array. How I'd like this map to work: when the user clicks on the shape, the shape's ID is passed to the getJSON function, and the object whose key/index matches that ID will be the only object retrieved from the JSON, and ultimately displayed in the div below the map.

Currently, within my getJSON function, I am using $.each( data.items, function( key, val ), but the problem with this is that the console is showing that the key is actually the index due to the array in my JSON file. In a previous version of my project, I formatted my JSON in plain object formation with keys (without the array). I used .html() and .append() to return the object whose key matched the shape's ID; but, the problem with that is that I had to hardcode in the 'fl' before val.state in the below:

```
$("#txtDOT").html("<p id='state " + key + "'>" + val.state + "'</p>")//quotes fixed
```

I am torn on whether or not to include the array in my JSON. Please advise on how to pass the clicked shape's ID to the getJSON function, and how to zero in on that specific object whose key, or index, matches the shape's ID. The current version of my code is below:

HTML showing one state shape and the script tags:

```
<div class="svg-container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="546.411px" height="328.782px" viewBox="0 0 546.411 328.782" style="enable-background:new 0 0 546.411 328.782;"
 xml:space="preserve" class="svg-content">
<g id="fl" data-key="fl">
    <polygon id="flPolygon" style="fill:#3E7AAC;stroke:#1A171B;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:10;" points="406.029,254.818..."/>
    <text id="flLetters" transform="matrix(1.0127 0 0 1 443.8125 272.377)" style="fill:#3E7AAC;stroke:#1A171B;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:10; font-family:'ArialMT'; font-size:6.19;">FL</text>
    </g>
</svg>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="exploreMap.js"></script>
```

JS all:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var items = [];

   $.getJSON("stateInfoList.json", function( data ) {
        console.log ( data );//whole JSON object

      $("g").on("click", function (e) {
        console.log(this.id);
        var $e = $(e.currentTarget);//target should be clicked shape but I can't tell yet
        //clicked.css("background", "blue");//clicked is not defined yet


        $.each ( data.items, function( key, val ){
          console.log ( key, val );//key is "01", val is whats inside json's { }s

          items.push( "<p id='state " + key + "'>" + val.state + "<p id='contacts'>" + val.contacts + "'</p></p>");
           console.log( "<p id='state " + key + "'>" + val.state + "<p id='contacts'>" + val.contacts + "'</p></p>");

              //add all <p> items to a <ul>
              $( "<ul>", { //later, style="display:none";>
                    "class": "my-new-list",

                     html: items.join( "" ) //this joins all or **selected element(s)** back into a ~nonformatted~ string.//join method only works with arrays, not jquery objects.

              }).appendTo( "#txtDOT" );//

                //jQuery Selector $() function w optional 2nd parameter to do a search within an event handler
                $("p").on("click", function (e) {//Using e is just a short for event. You can pass any variable name you desire.
                    var $e = $(e.target);//target is #txtDOT
                    clicked.css("background", "red");
                });

        });                         

      });

   });

});

//If I use plain object instead of array, this might work:
//$("#txtDOT").html("<p id='state " + key + "'>" + val.state + "'</p>"); 
//$("#txtDOT").append("<p id='contacts'>" + val.contacts + "'</p>");
```

JSON all:

```
{
  "items": [

    {
    "abv": "nh",
    "state": "NEW HAMPSHIRE DEPARTMENT OF TRANSPORTATION",
    "contacts": "Concrete Admixtures (CADD) \nBob Real, Research Supervisor/QPL, 555-555-5555, breal@dot.state.nh.us \n\nConcrete Curing Compounds (CCC) \nBob Real, Research Supervisor/QPL, 555-555-5555, breal@dot.state.nh.us"
    },
    {
    "abv": "fl",
    "state": "FLORIDA DEPARTMENT OF TRANSPORTATION",
    "contacts": "Concrete Admixtures (CADD)\nJane Smith, Product Evaluation Administrator, 999-999-9999, jane.smith@dot.state.fl.us\n\nHot-Mix Asphalt Crack Sealers (HMA CS)\nKaren Brown, Product Evaluation Administrator, 999-999-9990, karen.brown@dot.state.fl.us"
    } 

  ]
}
```

Thanks,
LB

Comment: Your quotes are messed up. Should be `'<p id="state ' + key + '">'`

Comment: Why do you want to load the JSON every time a user clicks?  Why don't you just load the data once on page load?  That's seems to be a lot of extraneous ajax calls.  If there is only one item per state that isn't a ton of data to just go ahead and load into an array.

Comment: Rob - Thanks, I fixed quotes. @Gary Storey - Thanks for recommending that I keep the array in my JSON instead of reformatting it into plain objects. How do I associate the clicked shape with the correct index? Do I need to manually type in a data-index attribute on each shape in my HTML? Could .index() somehow be used? Thanks for suggesting I load JSON once on page load. I moved my getJSON function above my onclick function in attempt to only load JSON on page load, so only array does the work when user clicks. Is this rearranged code the solution? (I'm still learning JavaScript.) Thanks - LB

Comment: The solution: I formatted my JSON as a plain object. Under my .each() method, I stored val in a variable, then used an if else statement to match the key with the clicked shape's ID. There was no need to add data-index attributes or the .index() method.

Answer (score 0):

The solution: I formatted my JSON as a plain object. Under my `.each()` method, I stored `val` in a variable, then used an `if else` statement to match the key in the JSON with the clicked shape's ID. There was no need to add data-index attributes to the inline html or use the `.index()` method.